# How do I pass arguments to a test case?

Tags: python

I am running my test suites using:

```
unittest2.TextTestRunner(verbosity=verbosity).run(module_suites)
```

How can I pass some string arguments to my test suites ?

Answer (score 0):

You can overload your run(...) function like this :

```
def run(function, arg1, arg2, ...)
```

for a defined number of arguments or :

```
def run (function, *args)
```

for an undefined number of arguments.

Comment: Let me try this and get back to you.